# Issues pushing user input into Typescript array due to type conflict

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class called friend, containing an array as a property:

```
export class Friend {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  bday: string;
  gifts: string[] = [];
}
```

I'm attempting to access this and push items into it, based on user input to a friend-detail component:

```
export class FriendDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() friend: Friend;


  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private friendService: FriendService,
    private location: Location,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getFriend();

  }

  getFriend(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.friendService.getFriend(id)
        .subscribe(friend => this.friend = friend);
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }

  addGift(): void {
    var giftinput = (<HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById("gift-input")).value;
    var gifts = this.friend.gifts;
    console.log(typeof(this.friend.gifts));
    console.log(this.friend.gifts);
    gifts.push(giftinput);
  }
}
```

The user input html looks like this:

```
<div *ngIf="friend">
  <h2>{{ friend.name | uppercase }} Details </h2>
  <div><span>id: </span> {{friend.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>Name:
      <input [(ngModel)]="friend.name" placeholder="name">
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>Birthday:
      <input [(ngModel)]="friend.bday" placeholder="bday">
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>Gift Ideas:
      <input id="gift-input" [(ngModel)]="friend.gifts" placeholder="gift">
      <p [(ngModel)]="friend.gifts" ngDefaultControl>{{friend.gifts}}</p>
      <button (click)="addGift()">add gift</button>
    </label>
    <!-- <button (click)="addGift()">Add Gift</button> -->
  </div>
</div>

<button (click)="goBack()">go back</button>
```

I don't believe this code is part of the problem, but just in case:

```
export class FriendService {
  //url to web api and friends object
  private friendsUrl = 'api/friends';


  getFriends(): Observable<Friend[]> {
    //this.messageService.add('FriendService: fetched friends');
    return this.http.get<Friend[]>(this.friendsUrl)
    .pipe(
      //_ refers to unused parameter
      tap(_ => this.log(`fetched friends`)),
      catchError(this.handleError('getFriends', []))
    );
  }

  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);
      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.messages}`);
      return of(result as T);
    }
  }

  getFriend(id: number): Observable<Friend> {
    //todo: send message after fetching the Hero
    //this.messageService.add(`FriendService: fetched friend id=${id}`);
    const url = `${this.friendsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Friend>(url).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`fetched friend id=${id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Friend>(`getFriend id=${id}`))
    );
  }

  updateFriend(friend: Friend): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(this.friendsUrl, friend, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`updated friend id=${friend.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<any>(`updateFriend`))
    );
  }

  addFriend(friend: Friend): Observable<Friend> {
    return this.http.post<Friend>(this.friendsUrl, friend, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((newFriend: Friend) => this.log(`added friend w/ id=${newFriend.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Friend>(`addFriend`))
    );
  }

  searchFriends(term: string): Observable<Friend[]> {
    if (!term.trim()) {
      return of([]);
    }
    return this.http.get<Friend[]>(`${this.friendsUrl}/?name=${term}`).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`found friends matching "${term}"`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Friend[]>('searchFriends', []))
    );
  }

  deleteFriend(friend: Friend | number): Observable<Friend> {
    const id = typeof friend === 'number' ? friend : friend.id;
    const url = `${this.friendsUrl}/${id}`;

    return this.http.delete<Friend>(url, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`deleted friend id=${id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Friend>('deleteFriend'))
    );
  }

  private log(message: string) {
    this.messageService.add(`FriendService: ${message}`);
  }

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessageService,) { }
}
```

When the addGift() function is called (button press) while the user input is empty, the print statements return 'object' and an empty array '[]'. However, as soon as I enter a value to the user input, the print statements show 'string' and the push function launches the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: gifts.push is not a function
```

What am I missing? Is the type changing, and why?

Comment: The value acquired from the input / `ngModel` is a string. How do you want a user's input to map to an array? One input for each gift would work, but I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: What is the output of your `console.log`s prior to the call to `gifts.push`?

Comment: You shouldn't use [(ngModel)]="friend.gifts" on your input: it's not supposed to contain all the friend's gifts, but only the next gift that will be added to the array when the button is clicked. Bind it to a string property (nextGift for example) of your component.

Comment: Also, <p [(ngModel)]="friend.gifts" doesn't make much sense: you can't enter anything in a <p>. It's not a form control.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley When the user input is empty, it prints '[]'. When the user input is not empty, it returns the string input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type is indeed changing.  You have stated in your class that .gifts is an array, but in your html you are using ngModel to bind it to a text input.  When means that as your user is typing in the box, you are actively reassigning that value as a string.

this is the line where you might want to rethink / remove the ngModel

```
<input id="gift-input" [(ngModel)]="friend.gifts" placeholder="gift">
```